# How to pass an array into a MySQLi query?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm having this query:

```
$mysqli->query("
      SELECT 
           itemid 
      FROM 
           inventories AS a 
      WHERE 
           ownerid = 1 IN(SELECT itemid FROM items WHERE itemid = a.itemid)"
);
```

What I'm trying to do, is to pass all itemid's from first SELECT to the second SELECT and ECHO them by fetch_assoc();

Currently it's returing only first row, without others.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish. `$mysqli->query("SELECT itemid FROM inventories AS a WHERE ownerid = 1);` should return all itemid's associated with ownerid = 1. Are you trying to filter out specific itemid's?

Answer (score 1):

I think your real problem is that `fetch_assoc()` returns one row.  Try `fetch_all($resulttype=MYSQLI_ASSOC)` or loop over your result and `fetch_assoc()` on each pass.